# What is the difference between 'standard' k-means clustering and fast k-means?

Tags: performance, k-means

How does the fast k-means algorithm work, and how is it different from standard k-means?

Comment: Fast is adjective that can be used by anyone, implement new heuristic on _k_-means. I don't think is indicate especial heuristic or method in _k_-means literature for example [this](https://github.com/ghamerly/fast-kmeans) implementation by a person that well-known in the literature named their _k_-means implementation as "Fast K-means".

Answer (score 1):

KMeans Clustering is randomly placing k centroids, one for each cluster.
***the farther apart the clusters are placed,  the better***

K-means++ is just an initialization procedure for K-means.
In K-means++ you pick the initial centroids using an algorithm that tries to initialize centroids that are far apart from each other.
You pick a point randomly and that's your first centroid, then you pick the next point based on a probability that depends on the distance to the first point, the further apart the point is the more probable it is. 
Then when you have two centroids you repeat the process, the probability of each point is based on its distance to the closest centroid to that point.

**This introduces an overhead in the initialization of the algorithm, but it reduces the probability of a bad initialization leading to a bad clustering result**.

Answer (score 0):

*Fast k-means* seems to be an alternative name for the [k-means++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) algorithm. The idea here is to use a more sophisticated "seeding procedure" for the initial choice of the center positions, whereas standard k-means uses a random distribution for these positions instead. 
Afterwards, the usual k-means algorithm is run on this improved starting configuration.

According to Wikipedia k-means++ usually converges in two or three iterations and often twice as fast as the standard k-means algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. But can you explain about " initial choice of the center positions" in Fast K-means?!

Comment: One just picks them in a sensible way. You know, k means initially chooses centers, and then until convergence attributes data points to these centers, readjust the centers, again attributes data to centers, readjusts, and so on. It's obvious that a well chosen initial configuration is helpful in this process. Read the details about the seeding procedure itself in the linked Wikipedia article.